# How can I create task with SpiffWorkflow?

Tags: python, workflow

I could not understand how to use SpiffWorkflow workflow engine. What means creating a task exactly and how can I do that?

Also I could not find **any** example which uses SpiffWorkflow. Who uses this engine? How can I find usage examples?

Comment: It looks like this is the documentation - https://github.com/knipknap/SpiffWorkflow/wiki

Answer (score 4):

I've found an example [here.](http://arekyao.github.io/blog/2013/10/02/workflow-engine-in-python/)

```
import sys, os
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),  '../../lib'))

from SpiffWorkflow.specs import *
from SpiffWorkflow import Task, Workflow
from SpiffWorkflow.storage import XmlSerializer

def on_entered_cb(workflow, task, taken_path):
    #print "entered:",task.get_name()
    return True

def on_ready_cb(workflow, task, taken_path):
    #print "ready:",task.get_name()
    return True

def on_reached_cb(workflow, task, taken_path):
    #print "reached:",task.get_name()
    return True

def on_complete_cb(workflow, task, taken_path):
    # Record the path.
    print "complete:",task.get_name()
    #print task.get_description()
    indent = '  ' * (task._get_depth() - 1)
    taken_path.append('%s%s' % (indent, task.get_name()))
    return True

class QuestionError(Exception):

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def __str__(self):
        return repr(self.value)

class QuestionWorkflow(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.serializer = XmlSerializer()

    def set_up(self,filename):
        # Test patterns that are defined in XML format.
        xml = open(filename).read()
        self.wf_spec = WorkflowSpec.deserialize(XmlSerializer(), xml, filename = filename)
        self.taken_path = self.track_workflow(self.wf_spec)
        self.workflow   = Workflow(self.wf_spec)


    def run(self, UserSelection, restart=False):

        if restart:
            self.workflow = Workflow(self.wf_spec)

        workflow = self.workflow
        condition_keys = []
        if UserSelection is None:
            UserSelection = {}

        task_data_dict = UserSelection.copy()

        while not workflow.is_completed():
            tasks = workflow.get_tasks(Task.READY)

            for t in tasks:
                print "Ready:", t.task_spec.name
                if  hasattr(t.task_spec, "cond_task_specs"):
                    for cond, name in t.task_spec.cond_task_specs:
                        for cond_unit in cond.args:
                            if hasattr(cond_unit, "name"):
                                condition_keys.append(cond_unit.name)


            flag_keys_in_user_select = True
            for cond_key in condition_keys:
                if not task_data_dict.has_key(cond_key):
                    print cond_key
                    flag_keys_in_user_select = False
                    break

            if not flag_keys_in_user_select:
                # some tast's condition's key not in input userselect dict
                return
            for t in tasks:
                t.set_data(**task_data_dict)

            workflow.complete_next()

        if not workflow.is_completed():
            raise QuestionError('invalid feature[%s]' % filename)

    def print_trace(self):
        path = '\n'.join(self.taken_path) + '\n'
        info = ""
        info += 'the workflowrun path:\n'
        info += '%s\n' % path
        print info


    def track_task(self, task_spec, taken_path):

        #reached event call back
        if task_spec.reached_event.is_connected(on_reached_cb):
            task_spec.reached_event.disconnect(on_reached_cb)
        task_spec.reached_event.connect(on_reached_cb, taken_path)

        #completed event call back
        if task_spec.completed_event.is_connected(on_complete_cb):
            task_spec.completed_event.disconnect(on_complete_cb)
        task_spec.completed_event.connect(on_complete_cb, taken_path)

        #enter event call back
        if task_spec.entered_event.is_connected(on_entered_cb):
            task_spec.entered_event.disconnect(on_entered_cb)
        task_spec.entered_event.connect(on_entered_cb, taken_path)

        #ready event call back
        if task_spec.ready_event.is_connected(on_ready_cb):
            task_spec.ready_event.disconnect(on_ready_cb)
        task_spec.ready_event.connect(on_ready_cb, taken_path)



    def track_workflow(self, wf_spec, taken_path = None):
        if taken_path is None:
            taken_path = []
        for name in wf_spec.task_specs:
            #print "track_workflow:",name
            self.track_task(wf_spec.task_specs[name], taken_path)
        return taken_path

if __name__ == '__main__':
    qw = QuestionWorkflow()
    qw.set_up("./case.xml")
    print "==========1st question=========="
    user_selct = {'man':'1'}
    qw.run(user_selct)
    print "==========2nd question=========="
    user_selct = {'man':'1', 'house': '2'}
    qw.run(user_selct)
    print "==========3rd question=========="
    user_selct = {'man':'1', 'house': '2', 'why': 'because you are a hero'}
    qw.run(user_selct)

    '''
    print "==========4th question========="
    user_selct = {'man':'1', 'house': '2', 'role':'5'}
    qw.run(user_selct)
    '''

    print "==========fix some question=========="
    user_selct = {'man':'1', 'house': '1', 'role':'5'}
    qw.run(user_selct,True)

    print
```

Answer (score 1):

We have developed Zengine extended version of SpiffWorkFlow with improved functionality. You can find it [here](https://github.com/zetaops/zengine), and you can see [here](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ulakbus.org%2Fwiki%2Fzengine-ile-is-akisi-temelli-uygulama-gelistirme.html&edit-text=) to find out usage examples.

In short;

Zengine BPMN workflow based framework with Tornado, Rabbit AMQP, advanced permissions, extensible scaffolding features and more.

Built on top of following major components;

SpiffWorkflow: Powerful workflow engine with BPMN 2.0 support.
Tornado: Tornado is a Python web framework and asynchronous networking library.
Pyoko: Django esque ORM for Riak KV store.
RabbitMQ: Fast, ultrasharp AMQP server written with legendary Erlang lang.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps take a look at this file will help

https://github.com/knipknap/SpiffWorkflow/blob/master/SpiffWorkflow/specs/WorkflowSpec.py

and these docs
https://github.com/knipknap/SpiffWorkflow/wiki